# recordings of eras of Latin

Tags: vulgar-latin, late-latin, old-latin

I'm not sure if this question is allowed here or not but are there recordings of eras of Latin  (Old Latin, Late Latin, and Vulgar Latin) and also African Latin that are recited as perfectly     as Thomas Bervoets (for example https://www.stilus.nl/horatius/index-latine.htm) does?

Comment: Welcome, Ana Maria. Do you think you could provide a little bit more information on what exactly you're looking for? Are you looking for comparisons of pronunciation or something else?

Comment: Comparisons of pronunciation would be good but what I'm looking for is individual recordings of Old Latin, Late Latin, Vulgar Latin, and African Latin!

Comment: Here's this one video that I found! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdQawsU2RFg&t=306s The women that is speaking in this video is excellent at pronouncing Vulgar Latin although she still sounds English when she is pronouncing the words!

Answer (score 4):

**Latinitium** has a large selection of Latin recitations -about 100- mostly classical but covers other eras too, freely available at https://www.latinitium.com/latin-audio-archive . This is probably the closest to having a sort of unified 'archive' of all types of Latin recordings/recitations.

**Luke Ranieri**'s audio section (https://lukeranieri.com/audio/) is also an excellent source of recitations; most of them are paywalled but there are free samples as well, and Ranieri is very active in all matters of Latin and Greek dialects and pronounciation diachronically.

Other than the above, the **Harvard Department of Classics** has a collection of classical Latin poetry and prose recitations at https://classics.fas.harvard.edu/latin-recitations, and **Rhapsodoi** is another recource of finding classical Latin recited at https://rhapsodoi.org/index-of-latin-recitations/ .